# Find out which permission is merged from which lib

Tags: android, gradle, permissions, android-manifest

Assume that I include multiple libs in my Android Studio Project.

The Manifest of the libs are automatically merged by the ManifestMerger.

After that I've got some more additional permissions.

**Question:**

What's an easy way to find out which permission is required(merged) by which lib, without checking the Manifest of each lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the log created by the Manifest Merger here:

```
app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt
```

For example you can find something like this for `android.permission.INTERNET`:

```
uses-permission#android.permission.INTERNET
ADDED from /MyApplication/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-66
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-66
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-analytics/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-67
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-66
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-appinvite/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-67
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-maps/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-66
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-gcm/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-67
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-maps/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-66
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-maps/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-66
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-measurement/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-67
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-analytics/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-67
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-66
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-wallet/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-66
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0] /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-maps/8.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-66
    android:name
        ADDED from /MyApplication/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6:22-64
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed.